# Moving data between MVC objects

Tags: spring-mvc

I have 2 tables.  One is a list of parts with a key = PID.  The second is a list of parttickets.
This is how I've currently setup the controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/addNewParttickets")
public ModelAndView addNewParttickets(@RequestParam Integer pidKey) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("parts", partsDAO.findPartsByPrimaryKey(pidKey));
    mav.addObject("parttickets", new Parttickets());
    mav.addObject("newFlag", true);
    mav.setViewName("parttickets/addNewParttickets.jsp");
    return mav;
}
```

My question is, how do I set partickets.pid = parts.pid?  Would it be best to do this in the addObject call?  (if so, then how?)  Or is it best to do this in the jsp file as part of the form setup?
Or am I totally in left field here and need to do more research?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about it all wrong.  Easy enough to do -

```
    Parttickets parttickets = new Parttickets();
    Parts parts = partsDAO.findPartsByPid(pidKey);

    parttickets.setPid(parts.getPid());
```